# alpine docker image for cakephp

Tags: alpine-linux, cakephp3

I am struggling trying to dockerize an app for CakePHP 3. I already did with a PHP apache image but it is pretty big, for that reason I am trying to dockerize the app in an alpine container. I also need npm, but I cannot install npm, I have received a lot of errors during the build. After executing the container the "npm" command is "not found" either.
This is the docker file I have:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

ARG ENV=development
ARG UID=1000
ARG HOST_OS=Linux
ENV APP_ENV=$ENV
ENV HOST_OS=$HOST_OS

RUN apk add --update nodejs-current npm

WORKDIR /var/www/html/webroot     // The package.json is here.

# Setup GD extension
RUN apk add --no-cache  \
      bash \
      curl \
      supervisor \
      freetype \
      libjpeg-turbo \
      libpng \
      freetype-dev \
      libzip-dev \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd \
    && apk del --no-cache \
      freetype-dev \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

RUN npm install -g npm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip bcmath
```

The errors:

```
build/libtool.m4:70: AC_LIBTOOL_SETUP is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:52: _AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:39: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:161: the top level
configure.ac:161: warning: The macro `AC_LANG_C' is obsolete.
configure.ac:161: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/c.m4:72: AC_LANG_C is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:561: _LT_AC_LOCK is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:1184: AC_LIBTOOL_SYS_HARD_LINK_LOCKS is expanded from...
build/libtool.m4:2727: _LT_AC_LANG_C_CONFIG is expanded from...
....... // I stoped here because there are more in red color.
```

**UPDATE**: The npm package is not installed, when I execute the container "npm -i" does not work, I can see "not found". I can install the package directly in the container, but it is not installed during the build.

Comment: The red text is warnings. The build worked for me I got a 197mb image using your Dockerfile

Comment: Did the installation of npm work for you when you execute the container? If I do "docker exec -it <container_name> sh" and after "npm -i" , the command it is not found.